# modulus of linear functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

Would the left hand side equal right
can i take the out the number 2 from modulus because it can be factorised.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it stems from the fact that $|ab| = |a||b|$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct. Dividing by 2 on the left hand side makes the two inequalities equivalent.